# Align text when using tableGrob or grid.table in R

Tags: r

When creating a table using tableGrob or grid.table.
Is there way to align the text inside the table? First column to the left, and the other columns to the right? Rather than the default "center".

Thank you!

something like this: where I want column "a" alligned to the left.

```
a <- c("one","two","thirty five")
b <- c(1, 2, 3)
c <- c(4, 5, 6)

data <- data.frame(a,b,c)

windows()

grid.table(
  data,
  gpar.coretext=gpar(fontsize = 12),            
  gpar.coltext = gpar(fontsize = 12),            
  gpar.rowtext = gpar(fontsize = 12),            
  gpar.corefill = 
    gpar(fill = "green", alpha = 0.5, col = NA),           
  h.even.alpha = 0.5,            
  equal.width = FALSE,            
  show.rownames = FALSE,            
  show.vlines = TRUE,           
  padding.h = unit(15, "mm"),            
  padding.v = unit(8, "mm")            
)
```

Comment: I'm not sure why this is getting the vote to close.  It is lacking reproducible example but it's not really a localized question.

Comment: Would you please share us a bit of your code, and explain more?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for? There is a `core.just` parameter of the `format()` call.

```
require("gridExtra")

n=5
df<- data.frame(x=rnorm(n),y=rnorm(n),z=sample(letters[1:2],n,replace=T))


g1<-tableGrob(
format(df, digits = 1,
     scientific=F,big.mark = ","),
     core.just="left",
     #core.just="right",
     #col.just="right",
     gpar.coretext=gpar(fontsize=8), 
     gpar.coltext=gpar(fontsize=9, fontface='bold'), 
     show.rownames = F,
     h.even.alpha = 0,
     gpar.rowtext = gpar(col="black", cex=0.7,
                            equal.width = TRUE,
                            show.vlines = TRUE, 
                            show.hlines = TRUE,
                            separator="grey")                     
)

grid.draw(g1)
```

Comment: Thank you!!! The Left column is exactly as I wanted. When I run your code on my data, the inputs in the other columns were aligned differently (some to the center, some to the left). Will have to research the     format() in more details, to figure this out. Thank you!

Comment: i want to make my last column and last row as bold. please let me know how it can be done. I am either able to make all the rows and columns bold. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29340345/make-first-and-last-row-of-a-dataframe-bold-using-tablegrob please help

Answer (score 10):

With gridExtra v>=2.0.0, the parameters are now controlled via nested lists (themes),

```
library(gridExtra)
library(grid)
n=5
d <- data.frame(x=rnorm(n),y=rnorm(n),z=sample(letters[1:2],n,replace=T))

m <- format(d, digits = 1, scientific=F,big.mark = ",")

mytheme <- ttheme_default(core = list(fg_params = list(hjust=0, x=0.1, 
                                                       fontsize=8)),
                          colhead = list(fg_params = list(fontsize=9, 
                                                          fontface="bold"))
                          )
g1 <- tableGrob(m, theme = mytheme, rows=NULL)
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(g1)
```

Answer (score 3):

To set a "transparent" background, use the `ttheme_minimal` with `hjust` to set text alignment.

```
theme_1 <- ttheme_minimal(core = list(fg_params = list(hjust = 0, 
                                                           x = 0.1, 
                                                    fontsize = 9)),
                          colhead = list(fg_params = list(fontsize = 12, 
                                                          fontface = "bold")))
```

You can then apply the theme to the `tableGrob` like this:

```
gridExtra::tableGrob(df_tbl, theme = theme_1, rows=NULL)
```